# Mysql general query log tool to play back queries in time?

Tags: mysql, logging, benchmark

I am trying to reproduce production activity in time for benchmarking purposes from the mysql general query log. I'd like to be able to use the date data from the log to reprduce the time intervals between queries. So if query 1 executes at 9AM and query 2 executes at 10AM then I want the benchmark to execute these queries an hour apart.

Is there are a tool that does this? I'm assuming there is. The maatkit tool `mk-log-player` parses out the queries but replaying them with no delay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particular tool to do this. I'd write a simple script to parse log and extract queries to be run.